# Why is voltage and current at a node 0?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, kirchhoffs-laws

I am studying through Kirchoff's current law and following with a multimeter.

As per the law, I could see the current entering and exiting the node is same,  0.17mA. Also the voltage is 2.56 volts.

***Voltage before node***

[image: Voltage before node]

***Voltage after the node***

[image: Voltage after node]

When I measure the voltage at the node (series connection between the two parallel circuits,) it is zero.

Why is the voltage and current at the node zero?

***Voltage at the node***

[image: Voltage at the node]

***Update:***

The same thing happens when I measure this with voltage as well. Getting reading of 2.58V in nothe the places, but 0 at the node.

Comment: You're not measuring the current correctly.

Comment: Current meter has to be in series with the branch that is being measured; what you have in the photos is putting the current meter in parallel with the branch you're trying to measure.

Comment: The ends of the DMM leads are shorted when you're in current mode, so you're actually just shorting out those resistors.  You get zero when you short out a wire since the wire already shorts itself out.

Comment: Didn't find a good dupe on this site, but there is a decent tutorial on current measurement at https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-multimeter/measuring-current -- Note that the meter itself must be the only path that the current can flow through. Putting the probes across a component is correct for measuring voltage, but incorrect for measuring current.

Comment: @Hearth, Thanks. Same thing happens when I am majoring voltage as well. I think majoring volatage in parallel is correct .

Comment: @Marku , Thanks. Same thing happens when I am majoring voltage as well. I think majoring volatage in parallel is correct .

Comment: @Simsons It is "measure" and "measuring". Not "major" and "majoring".

Comment: @Simsons Try making the left resistor a different value than the right resistor and redo your experiment. You'll see the numbers are different the way you are doing the measurements. An ideal ammeter has zero resistance, thus, you put the ammeter in series with the resistor, not in parallel. Voltage measurements, you measure across (in parallel) the resistor in question.

Comment: @DKNguyen, Thanks. Updated.

Comment: @MarkU, I have updated the question with pics for voltage reading as well. I am still getting 0 for the voltage.

Comment: @Simsons Yes, there is zero voltage across a wire. This indicates that it's a good wire and not a resistor.

Comment: You need to talk about the voltage **across** an element or **between** two points in the circuit. With out a schematic and a designated reference point, saying "the voltage **at**" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from your pictures, in the first two pictures you are measuring the voltage across resistors, and if you have a current through them then you surely get a voltage. But, in the last picture I can see that you are measuring voltage across a wire, and since a wire doesn't have a resistance (at least not in low frequencies) you won't read a voltage. We could help you better if provide your schematic.